# How to get main window when using NSMainStoryboardFile

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, xcode-storyboard

I'm writing a storyboard based Mac app, and I want my app delegate to get a reference to the main window so that I can show it from `-applicationShouldHandleReopen:hasVisibleWindows:` if closed.

From what I can tell the docs don't really mention how the storyboard is loaded, but the window is instantiated sometime after `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.

Does anyone have any idea about how to do it?